# Nashorn bug JDK8u40 "Method Code Too Large"

Tags: nashorn

The Nashorn eval of a js script on a method invoked on an object that is actually implemented by its superclass, delegates to a dynamic linker. This iterates through the entire hierarchy of the class and builds a classWriter on all its methods. If the superclasses contain few 1000's of methods it still emits the "Method Code Too Large" error exceeding the 64K limit JDK defines.

var obj = SomeInitCode.getObjectOfCustomType();

var xyz = obj.doSomeOperation() // this is method implemented on obj's superclass which is **Abstract**.

The Nashorn engine then tries to create an Adaptor which thereafter fails as there are in my case about 6000+ methods on the Abstract class and its superclasses.

Ref:

http://skrishnamachari.wordpress.com/2014/06/18/nashorn-bug/

Also is there a possibility to access the latest Nashorn source to be able to quickly debug through. Atleast find a hack/ validate and have it stick for our use till some final patch is provided.

Comment: NashornLinker.getSamTypeConverter(Class<?>, Class<?>), If the "isSourceTypeGeneric" is forced to false, it does work fine in the tests that give the error. So is it as you state an overeager need to create adapter classes..?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, latest developer repo for the 8u branch is available at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/nashorn. It will soon become the development stage for 8u60, though but you'll be able to get the 8u40 code here then: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u40-dev/nashorn. FWIW, 8u and 9 code for Nashorn are almost entirely identical so far (so far, we backported everything from 9 to 8u except for some parser changes that don't actually affect externally observable behavior).

Speaking of your problem: if we need to generate a JS-to-Java adapter class for a Java class of +6000 methods, then it'll indeed fail as the constructor of the class will have code for looking up 6000 JS functions in the adapted object, and that'll indeed be too large. We might supposedly come up with some different way of organizing the constructor but it seems like an awful lot of work for a hopefully rare case of people having humongous classes.

Alternatively, we could check whether we only create adapters when they're really needed. Your above code snippet looks like the adapter is not strictly necessary at that point, so it might be that in certain scenarios we're overeager to create adapter classes. Do you have a full stack trace maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the quick note..!!.. I will push in the stack too. Is there a email id/ anyother link I can send it as attachment..?

Comment: TypeConverterFactory$1$1.computeValue(Class<?>) line: 124 
..
TypeConverterFactory$1$1(ClassMap<T>).get(Class<?>) line: 150 
.. 
..
TypeConverterFactory.getTypeConverterNull(Class<?>, Class<?>) line: 349 
TypeConverterFactory.asType(MethodHandle, MethodType) line: 246 
..
NashornBeansLinker$NashornBeansLinkerServices.asTypeLosslessReturn(MethodHandle, MethodType) line: 197 
..
SingleDynamicMethod.getInvocation(MethodHandle, MethodType, LinkerServices) line: 191 
.. 
NashornBeansLinker.getGuardedInvocation(LinkRequest, LinkerServices) line: 84

Comment: MethodWriter.getSize() line: 2065 
JavaAdapterBytecodeGenerator$1(ClassWriter).toByteArray() line: 856 
JavaAdapterBytecodeGenerator.createAdapterClassLoader() line: 296 
.. 
.. 
..
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line:.. 
JavaAdapterFactory.createAdapterInfo.. 
JavaAdapterFactory.getAdapterInfo(.. line: 192 
JavaAdapterFactory.isAutoConvertibleFromFunction(.. line: 180 
NashornLinker.isAutoConvertibleFromFunction(.. line: 229 
NashornLinker.getSamTypeConverter(Class<?>, Class<?>) line: 162 
NashornLinker.convertToType(Class<?>, Class<?>) line: 116

Comment: Thank you; I think that's enough information, I can work from this. It seems that we are generating adapters in some cases to query it about properties of the class it adapts. It would be possible to obtain that information even without generating an adapter class. I filed https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8067935 to track this; without promising anything I believe I will be able to make this better for Java 8u60.

Comment: I'm sharing an example of where this is a real problem. I'm want to run the library Parse5 for working with DOMs but this file causes the 'Method code too large' error https://github.com/inikulin/parse5/blob/master/lib/tokenization/named_entity_trie.js.