# JDK 8 Nashorn Javascript Engine limitation

Tags: javascript, java, java-8, nashorn, capacity

I am moving to `JDK 8` and had to use `Nashorn` to process `JS` files.

I used to be able to process a `300MB` file having 1 huge function using **JDK 7 Rhino JS engine**. It should be noted that the `300MB` is a generated file that is processed by my tool, I know this is not good practice to have a single huge function in a huge file.

Now I am not able to and I am getting `java.lang.runtimeException: Class file too large!`, with the following stacktrace:

```
 at  jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase$BytecodeGenerationPhase.transform(CompilationPhase.java:431)
 at  jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase.apply(CompilationPhase.java:624)
 at  jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:655)
 at  jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.RecompilableScriptFunctionData.compileTypeSpecialization(RecompilableScriptFunctionData.java:725)
 at  jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.RecompilableScriptFunctionData.getBest(RecompilableScriptFunctionData.java:905)
 at  jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.getGeneric(ScriptFunctionData.java:384)
 at  jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.createGenericInvoker(ScriptFunctionData.java:282)
 at  jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.getGenericInvoker(ScriptFunctionData.java:276)
 at  jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:620)
 at  jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
 at  jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
 at  jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.callMember(ScriptObjectMirror.java:199)
 at  jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:386)
 at  jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeFunction(NashornScriptEngine.java:190)
```

I understand that the file size is ridiculous but it used to run on `Rhino`, I want to know what are `Nashorn` size limitations and if there is any way to overcome this.

I am using JDK 8u181. Is this fixed in newer JDK versions, now that 9 and 10 are available?

Comment: Nashorn creates JVM byte code, so it's the same as the Java limits.

Comment: A similar discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542742/nashorn-bug-jdk8u40-method-code-too-large

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for pointing that out. I now understand.

Comment: @NomanKhan I have seen that post before asking my question and thought it is a bit off of my issue. Apparently it isn't. They though didn't reach a solution. Is this planned to be enhanced or fixed? What are my alternatives to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nashorn is being deprecated in Java 11.

The best alternative today being [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/).